# How to set up classes in Sencha

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, extjs

Forgive me because I have not researched enough on this topic but I don't know how to google this one out. Here is my question, very often in jQuery Objects are instantiated something like this

```
myApp({
  property1: 'something',
  property2: true
});
```

I am learning Sencha and I want to be able to do something similar so here is my code.

```
var Person = new Ext.Class({
name: "Mr.unkown",

constructor: function(name){
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}, 

steps: 10,

constructor: function(steps){  
      this.steps = steps;
      return this; 
},

function(name, steps) {
    alert(name + " " + steps );

}
```

});

I want to be able to be able to do initialize it by doing something like this

```
var Jason = new Person({"Jason",10});
```

I know my question is very vague and not upto the point. But please help. Any links to any learning resources would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I was able to do it using the code below

```
var Person = new Ext.Class({
name: "Mr.unkown",

constructor: function(name){
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}, 

steps: 10,

constructor: function(steps){  
      this.steps = steps;
      return this; 
},

constructor: function(name, steps) {
    alert(name + " " + steps );
}
```

});

var Jason = new Person("Jason",10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `Ext.define` to declare a class.

```
Ext.define('Person', {
    constructor: function(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },

    getName: function() {
        return this.name;
    }
});

var o = new Person();
console.log(o.getName());
```

Relevant docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-define

Comment: I want to be able to initialize the object using 
var Jason = new Person({"Jason",10}); so that when i pass a value the result would be printed out. I hope it makes sense

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you want to pass an object config, the answer is still the same.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i wanted to be able to bass a config. I will try it out. Maybe I a mistake somewhere. Thanks